# Vegetable Existence

Tags: phrases, antonyms, phrase-meaning

I was reading Rabindranath Tagore's Short Stories and I came across a sentence. "I lead such a vegetable existence that a call to travel would fall upon me like a thunder-bolt". I understood from the context that a vegetable existence is more or less a boring experience without any enthusiasm.

Edit: 
Why is the term "vegetable" used here to denote that his life is plain?

Comment: Why  and with what possible  implications the author used one term is a matter of personal opinion and as such off- topic here. We can offer the different meanings and nuances the term "vegetable" may carry, but applying those to interpret what the author meant is a different matter.

Comment: @Josh61 I get it. If that is particular to the author, then I will not expect an answer which answers to that part of the question. I just thought that the usage of the word "vegetable" here might have an accepted origin.

Comment: It is used metaphorically as suggested. To vegetate and vegetative are more common expressions in that respect, but I think its usage is quite understandable. The expression "vegetable existence"  can be found, but its usages are more literal than figurative according to google books. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vegetable+existence+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvegetable%20existence%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Can I know why the question was downvoted? Is the question lacking any feature that questions in ELU must posses? Comments on my question would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Interpretation and discussion of literature is off-topic here. That said, personally I think what you suggest is complete and utter nonsense. There is absolutely nothing at all in the text that supports it in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Vegetables don't travel very far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the relevant term here is ***[to vegetate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vegetate)*** which is generally used metaphorically both for someone who  is in a state of coma or more commonly referring to boring, passive behaviours:

> - to live in a way that has no physical and mental activity:
>
>   - Are our kids spending too much time vegetating in front of the TV?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question.

To build my opinion on a solid basis, I will first use lexical meaning.

According to WordReference, *fruitful* refers to **"profitable, useful, beneficial"** and **"producing an abundant growth, as of fruit"** (See [fruitful - WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/fruitful))

Therefore, I suggest that it would not be proper to use *fruitful* to say you have an active, "vivid" life.

So in this context, I believe that *fruitful* is not the opposite of *vegetable (life)* which *-as a metaphor (persistent vegetative state)-* implies that the life of the one is calm/still.

Correct me if my perspective is wrong.

I hope this answers your question well.

Comment: I like this answer enough to upvote it, but a vegetative state is one in which no conscious thought is found, and certainly we don't think of vegetables as having consciousness. But I think the characteristic invoked here is one of locomotion -- animals move position under their own power; vegetables don't as they stay rooted. Note the author's reference to travel in the second sentence quoted.

Comment: @Onat Dergin Thanks for the answer. You have mentioned that vegetable life is calm or still. But I found the meaning to be *inactive; inert; dull; uneventful*. That is the reason I asked if the term has been used as an opposite to fruitful existence. Here is the meaning of [Vegetable Existence](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/vegetable).

Answer (score 1):

It may be a reference to people who are said to be "brain dead", eg in a coma following a serious accident, stroke etc, who can (offensively) be referred to as being "a vegetable".

It may be used (again, offensively) for people who aren't in in a coma but have a severely reduced mental function: for example who are unable to speak or move.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vegetable
2. Offensive Slang One who is severely impaired mentally and physically, as by brain injury or disease.

Perhaps the author is comparing his own life to that of someone in such a condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood the meaning of it. I was interested to know why the term vegetable is being used? Is it because fruitful is better since vegetables and fruits are in contrast?

Comment: "vegatable" in the sense used in my answer has got nothing to do with fruits:  I believe it's just a general reference to a vegetable's complete lack of any thinking ability (so it's compared to "animal" rather than "fruit": the whole "plant kingdom" if you like, which includes fruits).

Answer (score 1):

Etymology Online features the following explanation for vegetable:

> [Adjective](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vegetable): The meaning "resembling that of a vegetable, dull, uneventful; having life such as a plant has" is attested from 1854 (see vegetable (n.)).
>
> [Noun](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vegetable): Meaning "person who leads a monotonous life" is recorded from 1921; sense of "one totally incapacitated mentally and physically" is from 1976.

There is no mention of the meaning not being completely derived from the actual vegetable, which leads a rather boring life.